# Finding the minimum value of $\log _d a + \log _bd + \log _ac + \log _c b$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The question says to find the minimum value of $$\log _da + \log _bd + \log _ac + \log _cb$$ Given, $a,b,c,d \; \in R^+ -\Bigl(1\Bigl)$
**My approach:**
I used the AM-GM inequality and so we can see that $$\frac{\log _da + \log _bd + \log _ac + \log _cb}{4} \geq \Biggl(\log _da \cdot \log _bd \cdot \log _ac \cdot \log_cb\Biggl)^\frac{1}{4}$$ So the minimum value is, $$4\Biggl(\log _da \cdot \log _bd \cdot \log _ac \cdot \log _cb\Biggl)^\frac{1}{4}$$ 
Now, I wrote it as, $$\Biggl(\frac{\log_da}{\log_db} \cdot \frac{\log_ca}{\log_cb}\Biggl)^\frac{1}{4}$$
I am not sure what do to after this point. I also feel like we can use HM inequality but that will only give us, 
$$\log _da + \log _bd + \log _ac + \log _cb = \log _ad + \log _db + \log _ca + \log _bc $$

Comment: Any constraint on $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: Yes, $a,b,c,d \;\epsilon R^+ -\bigl(1\bigl)$

Comment: you should add the condition $a,b,c,d>0$ and $\neq 1$, in many solutions given we are assuming $a,b,c,d>1$ to apply AM-GM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Assuming positive values, You can use also

$$
\log_y x = \frac{\log x}{\log y}
$$

then

$$
\frac{\log a}{\log d}+\frac{\log d}{\log b}+\frac{\log c}{\log a}+\frac{\log b}{\log c}\ge 4
$$

NOTE

Another approach.

Assuming $a\ne 0,b\ne 0,c\ne 0,d\ne 0\;\;$ and calling

$$
f(a,b,c,d) = \frac ad+\frac db+\frac ca+\frac bc
$$

we have

$$
\nabla f = \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{d}-\frac{c}{a^2}=0 \\
 \frac{1}{c}-\frac{d}{b^2}=0 \\
 \frac{1}{a}-\frac{b}{c^2}=0 \\
 \frac{1}{b}-\frac{a}{d^2}=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving

$$
a = b = c = d \;\;\; \mbox{which gives}\;\;\;\; f(a,b,c,d) \ge 4 
$$

because

$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{2 c}{a^3} & 0 & -\frac{1}{a^2} & -\frac{1}{d^2} \\
 0 & \frac{2 d}{b^3} & -\frac{1}{c^2} & -\frac{1}{b^2} \\
 -\frac{1}{a^2} & -\frac{1}{c^2} & \frac{2 b}{c^3} & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{d^2} & -\frac{1}{b^2} & 0 & \frac{2 a}{d^3} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and for $a=b=c=d$

$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
 0 & 2 & -1 & -1 \\
 -1 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with eigenvalues $4,2,2,0$

Comment: Sorry, but hoe is the result obtained?

Comment: And what if $\log x <0$?

Comment: @gimusi Did you see the note at the answer top?

Comment: Yes we have $a,b,c,d>0$ and thus log can be negative. In this case we cannot use AM-GM.

Comment: @gimusi In this case we can use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. $a^2+b^2+c^2 
 \ge a b+ b c + ca $ No problem.

Comment: Ok but it should be clearly stated. Also others solutions given are assuming log positive which is not true and using AM-GM. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By [**Rearrangement inequality**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rearrangement_Inequality), since $\log$ is an increasing function, we have

$$\log _da + \log _bd + \log _ac + \log _cb=$$
$$=\frac{\log a}{\log d}+\frac{\log d}{\log b}+\frac{\log c}{\log a}+\frac{\log b}{\log c}\ge \frac{\log a}{\log a}+\frac{\log b}{\log b}+\frac{\log c}{\log c}+\frac{\log d}{\log d}=4$$

Comment: @PrakharNagpal I think that inthis case it is the correct way. We can't apply AM-GM since $\log x$ can be negative for $x>0$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\log _{ d } a+\log _{ b } d+\log _{ a } c+\log _{ c } b\geq 4(\log _{ d } a\cdot \log _{ b } d\cdot \log _{ a } c\cdot \log _{ c } b)^{ \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  }=\\ =4(\frac { \ln { a }  }{ \ln { d }  } \cdot \frac { \ln { d }  }{ \ln { b }  } \cdot \frac { \ln { c }  }{ \ln { a }  } \cdot \frac { \ln { b }  }{ \ln { c }  } )^{ \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  }=4$$

Comment: and what about $\log x <0$?

Comment: @gimusi Can you provide an example for any $log x < 0$

Answer (score -1):

Assuming all logarithms are $>0$

$$\dfrac{\log_da+\log_bd+\log_ac+\log_cb}4\ge\sqrt[4]{\log_da\log_bd\log_ac\log_cb}=1$$

using $$\log_xy=\dfrac{\log y}{\log x}$$

the equality occurs if $$\log_da=\log_bd=\log_ac=\log_cb$$

Comment: and what about $\log x <0$?

Answer (score -1):

I presume $a,\ldots,d>1$.
Then
$$\log_a d=\frac{\ln d}{\ln a}$$
etc. Then
$$\log_da \cdot \log_bd \cdot \log_ac \cdot \log_cb
=\frac{\ln a\ln d\ln c\ln b}{\ln d\ln b\ln a\ln c}=1$$
etc.

Comment: the assumption is $a,b,c,d>0$